# ExecuteScalar.Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

```
    Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
        If txtUsername.Text = Nothing Or txtPassword.Text = Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Enter Credential", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        End If
            If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            connection.Open()
        End If
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select count (*) from Admin where username = ? and password = ?, connection")
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUsername.Text
        Dim count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        If (count > 0) Then
            MsgBox("Login Succeed", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Else
            MsgBox("Account not found check credentials", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Anyone pls help me on this code...
this is for the login form

Comment: You're passing the connection as part of the SQL command string... `OleDbCommand("select count (*) from Admin where username = ? and password = ?, connection")` should be `OleDbCommand("select count (*) from Admin where username = ? and password = ?", connection)`

Answer (score 1):

You will want to exit the Sub if your validation fails. The `Return` statement accomplishes this.

You will want to declare count outside the Using blocks. You are going to show message boxes after evaluating count and we don't want connections hanging open while a user responds to a message box so we do the evaluation outside the Using blocks.

Keep you database objects local so you can control when they are closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks will accomplish this even if there is an error.

Correct your `OleDbCommand` constructor as @MathieuGuindon said in his comment.

I am so happy to see parameters being used that I hesitate to complain but the .Add method is preferred. http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html Actually, you are sort of mixing the up the 2 methods. The `.AddWithValue` second parameter expects the value not the `OleDbType`. It is of type Object so it doesn't produce a compile error but will blow up when it hits the database.

Don't open the connection until right before the .Execute  Connections are precious resources so you don't want to hold them open any longer than necessary.

And, finally, NEVER store passwords as plain text. I will leave it to you to research salting and hashing for password protection.

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUsername.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace) txtPassword.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Enter Credential", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        Return
    End If
    Dim count As Integer
    Using connection As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("select count (*) from Admin where username = ? and password = ?", connection)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUsername.Text
            connection.Open()
            count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        End Using
    End Using 'Closes and Disposes the connection
    If count > 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Login Succeed", "Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Account not found check credentials", "Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Mary, convert the old MsgBox to MessageBox.Show to make the rewrite complete :)